# Queryset is returning empty values even if there are values

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

```
    serializer_class = ProductQSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = ProductQ.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

```
My serializer class:
class ProductQSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductQ
        fields = '__all__'
```

When calling get method it returns:

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

Response is not showing the values.

Comment: Please share your `ProductQSerializer`. Likely it simply is an "empty" serializer.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not make it a `ModelSerializer`, only a simple `Serializer`, so this will not look into the `Meta` to generate a basic serializer.

```
#            inherit from ModelSerializer ↓
class ProductQSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductQ
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thank you ! It worked. haha I was looking at this for so long.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
class ProductQSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductQ
        fields = '__all__'
```